# Why isn't my cache behaviour for Amazon CloudFront gzipping my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using `CloudFront` and have an `S3` bucket with some `css`, `images` and `js`:

[image: my S3 bucket]

I checked on [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org) and saw my `css`, `images` and `js` are not being `gzipped`, for example, `all.js`, the 8th entry here:

[image: my results]

I read that I must create a `cache behaviour`, so I did, compressing, or so I thought, all js automatically:

[image: my Cache Behaviour]

However, still the same results in `webpagetest`.  I invalidated my `js`, waited but still I get the same result.

[image]

I'm clearly missing something here!  I haven't `gzipped` my files in the S3 bucket - is that a problem?  Can anybody spot my mistake(s) and tell me how to have my `css`, `images` and `js` from `CloudFront` `gzipped`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps somebody.  The problem is now solved.

I made the following `Invalidation`:

[image: Invalidation]

And then deleted the old `Behaviours` and added 3 new ones:

[image: New Behaviours]

Now all my resources are `Gzipped`:

[image: Success!]